# RegEx for replacing new lines

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace newlines where the second line doesn't start with a numeric character, I've used this sentence:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ / if m/\n[^0-9]/' *.txt
```

also I've tried with this:

```
sed -r 's/\n([^0-9])/\1/g' *.txt
```

The command prompt only shows me the entire file, but doesn't make any change, What I'm doing worng?

Comment: Can you please add sample inout with expected output in question.

Comment: Sed separates the input by lines, so the pattern space by default never contains the newline character itself.

Comment: See [How can I use sed to replace a multi-line string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26284/187122).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this input file:

```
$ cat file
1
2
foo
bar
3
etc
4
5
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^[0-9]/ ? ors: ""), $0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
1
2foobar
3etc
4
5
```

With GNU sed for `-z` to read the whole file as one string, `-E` to enable EREs, and to accept `\n` as meaning newline in the regexp:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/\n([^0-9])/\1/g' file
1
2foobar
3etc
4
5
```

Note that the awk solution, in addition to working portably with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box, only reads/stores one input line at a time and so will work efficiently and robustly for arbitrarily large files (as opposed to the sed solution which reads the whole file into memory and so YMMV for large files).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n\([^0-9]\)/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Open a two line window throughout the length of the file and if the second line of the window doesn't begin with an integer, remove the preceeding newline and repeat.